# What is the difference in using commons logging and slf4j in Spring Appliaction?

Tags: java, spring, logging, slf4j

I read from the spring documentation that it requires commons logging dependency on the classpath and it was made compulsory. Alternatively it was suggested to use slf4j. What is the difference in using slf4j and commons logging.  I am bit confused on which one to use. Please suggest the difference in using these two. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commons Logging and SLF4J are logging facades: you still need a real logging implementation (like log4j)
If you are writing a library that will be used in someone else's system, then you should use a logging facade because you do not know which logging framework they will use. In this case use SLF4J (Commons Logging is older and has some classloader issues).

If you control the whole application and can dictate which logging framework to use, you are free to choose your own preference. My preferred solutions are (in order of preference):

Logback
log4j
JDK logging (in my opinion, a case of 'not invented here' by SUN)

Comment: Sajid as u said can i use log4j if i use either of common loggings or slf4j? The only disadavantage is with commons logging demands additional dependencies which is not the case with slf4j. Is my understanding correct..

Answer (score 0):

slf4j is more efficient than commons logging. Moreover it acts as bridge- means you can change underlying logging provider with other than commons logging in future.

This link have good explaination. http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/08/why-use-sl4j-over-log4j-for-logging-in.html

Comment: thanks ashay. In the above thread u shared, it was mentioned that no need to manage multiple logging configuration for multiple libraries if you use slf4j.Can you elaborate this?

Comment: slf4j is accessor implementation. You have to use adaptor library- which connects any concrete logging framework available on classpath to slf4j.